# Modifying fields editability on a table level

Tags: axapta, x++

I have 2 tables, 1st table fields editability depends of a value of a NoYes enum from another related table. I want to know the best way to prevent edition of the fields on a table level.

I thought throwing an exeption on validatefield, but I don't know if it's the best way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throwing exceptions is not good here. Better is to prevent the change in the first place.

This is done in the `active` datasource method of the first table:

```
this.object(fieldNum(table1,field1)).allowEdit(table2.field2);
```

Comment: That is useful on a form level, thanks. But I was searching a way to prevent edition through table methods.

Comment: You could make a method on the table, then call from form.

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution that seems to work, on validateField() method of the table1.

```
public boolean validateField(FieldId _fieldIdToCheck)
{
    boolean ret;
    Table1 table1;

    ret = super(_fieldIdToCheck);

    select field1 from table1
        where table1.recid == this.recid;

    if (table1.field1)
    {
        ret = checkFailed("No editable");
    }

    return ret;
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: You have to check whether the field is selected (switch on `_fieldIdToCheck`). Also disabling the field for edit is more elegant, especially from the user perspective.

Comment: You should either correct your answer then accept it, or accept mine.